# How to display a console similar to chrome snippets on an html page so it can run Javascript commands that don't include alerts

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am learning Javascript currently with some experience in HTML and CSS. So I made a small website with different pages you can go to to try out little bits of code I've written. All of those use alert commands and a pop up. The things I'm trying to display on the website now are things I've been using the Chrome snippets for because of the console. Is there anyway to integrate a console into my webpage so when you hit the run button, it will run a preloaded set of code.

Final product I'd like to just click the button on the page and it run a program and show me in the console. Then maybe put several of these on a page to showcase everything I've learned such as the fizzbuzz problem or anything. I hope that makes sense. Thank you.

[image: Concept]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bordeaux said, not sure they have something in place to do it.

But you can re-write console.log() if needed.

Here is a simple example:

```html
<div id="fakeConsole"></div>
```

```js
const console = {

    log: function(str) {
    document.getElementById('fakeConsole').innerHTML+=str+"<br>";
  }

}

console.log('testMe')
console.log('testMe again')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ajxebhsg/

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to integrate the JS console onto a webpage.

You may try forking [JS bin](https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin) on GitHub (sort of like making a copy of the code so you can make your customizations), however that may be a bit complicated for the skillset you describe in your question.

[How to fork a GitHub repo](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo)

If you want to simply showcase your work, you can use [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/), [Repl](https://replit.com/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com).

Alternatively, if you just want to show your output, you can overwrite the `element.innerHTML` or `element.textContent` properties of a DOM element instead of using `console.log`.

[innerHTML docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

[textContent docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)